# Solving system of 1-D partial differential equations numerically in python (py-pde lib or any other)

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations, pde

I have the following system of partial differential equations:

[image]

Where
**c0** - constant,
**r** - independent spatial variable,
**t** - time variable,
**f(r, t)** - 1st unknown function,
**f_t(r, t)** - 2nd unknown function (actually it just represents first-order derivative of **f** over **t**: **f<sub>t</sub>(r, t)**),
**f<sub>r</sub>(r, t)** - first-order derivative of **f** over **r**,
**f<sub>rr</sub>(r, t)** - second-order derivative of **f** over **r**

The unknown **f(r, t)** and **f_t(r, t)** must be found within variables ranges r0..r1, t0..t1 (r0 = 5*10<sup>-4</sup>, r1 = 1, t0 = 0, t1 = 5*10<sup>-5</sup>)

Also there are the following initial conditions:

```
f(r, t0) = 0
f_t(r, t0) = 0
```

And the boundary condition:

```
f_t(r0, t) = ...<a function which is defined by set of points>...
# e.g.: scipy.interpolate.interp1d(array_of_t_values, array_of_F_values, kind='linear')
```

**How do I define all this and solve it numerically with py-pde (or any other suitable library) in python? And also I need to draw the resulting surfaces of f(r, t) and f_t(r, t)**

Here below I tried to modify existing example (py-pde), but I have no idea how to define the derivatives:

```py
from pde import FieldCollection, PDEBase, UnitGrid

class MyPDE(PDEBase):
    def __init__(self, c0=1500):
        self.c0 = c0

    def evolution_rate(self, state, t=0):
        f, f_t = state

        f = f_t
        f_t = (f.diff(r, 2) + 1/r * f.diff(r)) / self.c0

        return FieldCollection([f, f_t])


grid = UnitGrid([32, 32])
state = FieldCollection.scalar_random_uniform(2, grid)

eq = MyPDE()
result = eq.solve(state, t_range=100, dt=0.01)
result.plot()
```

Comment: You should not be too greedy with the variables names (for the derivatives), especially the line `f = f_t` is problematic, as you want to use `f` with its original content in the next line. Use `Df, Df_t` for the derivatives, `Df = f_t` etc. /// Also resolve the square of `c0` that is in the equation but not in the code.

Comment: @LutzLehmann the problem is that it's all just a pseudo code. I have no idea how to define those equations in code.